# Execute SSIS package on SQL Server 2012 from command line

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, cmd

I have an **SSIS** package that's deployed onto **SQL Server 2012**. Is it possible to execute this package from a **command line**? If yes, how do I execute this package?

Comment: yes it is. An internet search would tell you how...

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>dtexec /SQL "\"\DW_Load\my_package\"" /SERVER "\"myserver_name\"" /USER user123 /PASSWORD pass007 /REPORTING EWCDI

Answer (score 1):

[link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/21/sql-server-running-ssis-package-from-command-line/)

```
C:\>dtexec.exe /F "C:\ImportCSV\Package.dtsx"
```

[http://sql-developers.blogspot.in/](http://sql-developers.blogspot.in/2012/09/different-ways-to-execute-ssis-packages.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are Plenty of Examples that'll list you to exec from cmd line a simple search would heve been enough as @Mitch said:

Here are the helpful links

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/21/sql-server-running-ssis-package-from-command-line/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140258(v=sql.105).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138023(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the SSIS Packages can be executed from command line ::

```
C:\>dtexec.exe /F "C:\myfolder_vijj06\Package_name.dtsx" -- file path
```

[see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138023%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)